# Windows 10 native SSH jump host error

Tags: windows-10, ssh

When I tried connecting to a machine via a jump host using the Microsoft provided binairies, I get:

```
C:\>ssh -J hop dest
CreateProcessW failed error:2
posix_spawn: No such file or directory
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I'm using windows 10 without WSL.

```
C:\>ssh -V
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5

C:\>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.557]
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/956613/windows-10-ssh-proxycommand-posix-spawn-no-such-file-or-directory

The workaround is, you have to use the full path to ssh:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -W %h:%p hop" dest
```

Comment: Seems the fix will be rolled out soon^TM https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/18#issuecomment-507258777